# RTP Packet Loss with Freeswitch in Default Mode for a Video Call

Tags: sip, voip, wireshark, rtp, freeswitch

I am using Freeswitch in Default mode and two linphone android apps for video calls.But i am facing huge RTP loss in almost all the networks and video is getting stuck.

What i found after analysing the wireshark capture is that Freeswitch is forwarding initial RTP's to some private port and after that RTPs are being sent on the public router.I also found that there is a difference between the RTP received on A-leg/B-leg and RTP forwarded on A-leg/B-leg.

I can share some more details with screen shots of wireshark capture.
Kindly help me to figure ourt below things:

1. Why Freeswitch sends some of the packets to private port directly?
2. Why there  is difference between the RTP received on Freeswitch and sent out from Freeswitch?

I can share some more details with screen shots of wireshark capture.

Comment: Are your linphones behind a router/firewall? Sounds like it could be a NAT issue.

Comment: yes there is NAT inbetween but i got the huge RTP loss on mobile data network as well.Mainly i get good quality if a have good network bandwidth only even for the NATed enviornnment.

Can we minimize this affect anyhow for moderate netwrok conditions??